# Quark family/generation quantum numbers

Tags: standard-model, quarks, weak-interaction

Shouldn't strangeness and charm be essentially the same quantum number, the eigenvalue of the family operator for family #2 of the quarks, and similarly for top and bottom, for family #3?  It appears that the differing names are just a convenience in distinguishing them due to the widely differing masses between the two different weak isospin states in the same family. Family number should be the same (for the particle, and opposite for the anti-particles, of course) for both isospin projection states -- it's the weak isospin z-projection eigenvalue that distinguishes them in a complete eigenvalue set. All the other eigenvalues should be the same.  The Particle Data Group doesn't seem to think so though, since their tables distinguish charm from strangeness and bottomness from topness.

Comment: What *are* you saying? That two particles with different masses and different charges should not be distinguished? You also have a deeply unsound appreciation of families, a substantially arbitrary feature of convention and convenience. Weak interaction mixing scrambles families to  all but make them meaningless. Consider neutrinos!

Comment: The strange and charm quarks are both in family #2 of the quarks.  A family eigenvalue of 2 of the family operator would suffice for them rather than having separate designations since they are already distinguishable by other quantum numbers anyhow, just as you say.

Comment: No, the weak isospin z-component does *not* determine one of these quarks in terms of the other, because of weak mixing, the *heart* of the SM fermion sector. There is *no redundancy* in the fit. See answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDG does things just right: there is no other way. Your scheme might have some arguable merit in the absence of weak mixing, the 500 lb gorilla in the room, but, as it stands, it is meaningless.

> It appears that the differing names are just a convenience in distinguishing them due to the widely differing masses between the two different weak isospin states in the same family. Family number should be the same (for the particle, and opposite for the anti-particles, of course) for both isospin projection states -- it's the weak isospin z-projection eigenvalue that distinguishes them in a complete eigenvalue set.

The basis of your error is misappreciation of the *differing* roles of flavor (mass eigenstates) and weak isospin states. The six flavors used, upness, down-ness, charm, strangeness, top and beauty, correspond to mass eigenstates, the six quarks we know. In the lepton sector, the three charged leptons and the three neutrino mass eigenstates, (hopefully) temporarily dubbed 1, 2, and 3.

By the sharpest of contrasts, the members of the weak isodoublets are distinctly ***not*** these flavor eigenstates; in your case, people have chosen the convention of parameterizing the quark doublets as *(c,s')*, where *s'* is a linear combination of *all three generations'* down quarks, *d,s,b*. Because the mixing in the quark sector is de facto *small*, one pretends that $s'\approx s\cos\theta -d\sin\theta \approx s$, where *θ* is the largest mixing angle, the "Cabbibo" one, so one blinks and *thinks* of the weak isodoublet as being *(c,s)*, confident that this reversible metaphor would not impede their thinking at the end of the day.

But, at the end of the day, one also needs the 6 flavor names to peg down the real propagating degrees of freedom, and contrast them to the weak isodoublet members to describe this mixing in the first place.

This easy confusion is completely avoidable in the lepton sector, where the mixing is big, so as to make assignment of the neutrinos to generations ambiguous, or arbitrary. That is, before the ordering/hierarchy of the neutrino masses is confirmed experimentally, one does not even *dare* assign them to generations firmly. The convention is you just throw them into the 3 generations in increasing mass order, presently unconfirmed. But if you have marveled at the supreme confusion of popsicle graphs or the centrality of barycentric coordinates for them you appreciate the sheer definitional slop involved.

Comment: Thanks, good point. I was overlooking the CKM matrix entirely.  I still do have trouble with the concept of mass eigenstate for a permanently confined particle like the quark.

Comment: Confined quarks can still be studied through current algebra and lattice QCD, and their masses can be inferred/determined indirectly, and tabulated in PDG...